# Float Image to Left of Paragraph (Text)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image that I need to float left and have the paragraph of text automatically show up on the right.

For instance:

```
<div class:"floated-image"><img src="img/fox.png" alt="Fox logo">
<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the log. <a>The fox is here.</a>
</p></div>

 .floated-image{
    float: left;
 }
```

Unfortunately, this is not working any ideas? I won't get my materials for school till Monday and I would like to work this out!!  I've done everything else but this code and I have attempted to place the code within the paragraph.
CSS:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this? it can be display `flex`, `inline-flex`, `-webkit-box`

```css
 .floated-image {
   float: left;
   display:flex;
 }
```

```html
<div class="floated-image">
<img src="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yi/r/odA9sNLrE86.jpg" alt="Fox logo">
  <p>The quick brown fox jumped over the log. <a>The fox is here.</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<div class:"floated-image">` is wrong, `<div class="floated-image">` is correct.

*Use this code :*

```
.floated-image img {
    float: left;
 }
```

```css
.floated-image img {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="floated-image">
  <img src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg" alt="Fox logo">
  <p>The quick brown fox jumped over the log. <a>The fox is here.</a></p>
</div>
```

IF you want `.floated-image` be floated too.

*Use this code :*

```
.floated-image {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid;
 }

 .floated-image img {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
 }
```

```css
.floated-image {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid;
 }

 .floated-image img {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right:5px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="floated-image">
  <img src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg" alt="Fox logo">
  <p>The quick brown fox jumped over the log. <a>The fox is here.</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a class that requires the aforementioned naming structure in CSS and there is more than one image...

Comment: @JanineMcDaniel ,OK, use .floated-image img instead of img.see updated post.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<img style="height: 200px; width: 200px; float: left;" src="https://developers.google.com/search/images/searchHome-Amp.svg" alt="Fox logo">


<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the log. <a>The fox is here.</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Learn more about floats here - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp